# I can not make the array global

Tags: java, arrays

I need to write the arrays in a single line and carry it over through several different classes. here is my code so far. How would I go about making the arrays global? I am very confused. 
    This how I was taught through my online course.
        public class GravityV1
        {

```
 String[] planet= {"Mercury", "Venus","Earth","Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus","Pluto"};
 int[] diameter = { 4876, 12107, 12755, 6794, 142983, 120536, 51117, 49527, 2390};
 double[] mass= { 3.30e23,4.87e24,5.97e24,6.42e23,1.90e27,5.69e26, 8.66e25, 1.03e26, 1.31e22};



public  double calcgravity(double g, double r, double m)
{

g=(6.67e-11*m)/r;
    return g;
}
public static void printdata()
{

    System.out.println ("Planetary Data");
    System.out.println("Planet");
    System.out.printf("%8s", "Diameter (Km)");
    System.out.printf("%8s", "Mass (Kg)");
    System.out.printf("%10s", "g(ms^-2)");
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    for (int index=0; index<9; index++)
    {System.out.println( planet[index]);
    System.out.printf("%8f", diameter[index]);
    System.out.printf("%8f", mass[index]);

}
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{

     }
}
```

Comment: What language is this supposed to be and why is the code formatted so horribly ?

Comment: You need to learn what the `static` keyword means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual pattern would be: `public static final`. That is a globally accessible and unmodifiable array reference:

```
public class GravityV1 {   

  public static final String[] PLANETS = {  "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Pluto"};
  public static final int[] DIAMETERS = { 4876, 12107, 12755, 6794, 142983, 120536, 51117, 49527, 2390};
  public static final double[] MASSES = { 3.30e23, 4.87e24, 5.97e24, 6.42e23, 1.90e27, 5.69e26, 8.66e25, 1.03e26, 1.31e22};

  // ...
```

Note, that the naming conventions ask for capital names for constants (final statics). And that storing the three properties in three different array is not the best design. You should introduce a new class that holds those properties for each planet. Something like

```
public class Planet {
   private String name;
   private double mass;
   private int diameter;

   // Constructor

   // getters for the three fields
}
```

Comment: i worry when i see public next to a variable :) is this saying it can be done rather than should be?

Comment: fields shouldn't be public but I think that it's still OK for constants. I've added an improvement, although, enums would be even better.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. Make them static members of one of your classes.
2. Just pass arrays as arguments each time you need them in a different place.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the arrays public static for it to be globally accessible. Static members are class members and do not require an object instantiation.

It appears that you want to create a list of constants (the planet array certainly looks that way). You could use enums for this.

```
public enum Planets {

    MERCURY, VENUS, EARTH, MARS, JUPITER, SATURN, URANUS, PLUTO

}
```

EDIT: Consider the Planet enum in this example

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: But then you should add the diameter and mass properties to the enums too.

Comment: @Andreas_D Thanks for pointing that out. Since the planets and their respective mass and diameter are constants it'd make sense to use enums. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html has a good example.